# Element selection in GTM

Tags: html, css, google-analytics, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm having difficulty isolating specific click event which means we are missing out on reporting sales.

Essentially we have a - and + icon that sit within a table. The icons are enclosed in a field, and the user can click anywhere in the field including on and off the icon to add to basket. The area around the icon is small, but still not unlikely that a customer will click slightly off of the "+" sign. I figure I would set up an OR trigger saying "IF plus clicked OR area around plus clicked then fire an event" matching the CSS of the click elements.

Code is as follows

```
'''div class="ts-grid-cartQuantity ts-flex--row"
button class="ts-grid-cartQuantity-button ts-grid-cartQuantity-button--topBottomLeftRadius"
i class="fas fa-minus ts-white" /button
input class="ts-grid-cartQuantity-input poppins-regular--13-28" type="number" step="1">
button class="ts-grid-cartQuantity-button ts-grid-cartQuantity-button--topBottomRightRadius" data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-103516397_45="16971" data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen-103516397_45="16971" data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time-103516397_45="100" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-103516397_45="1">
/div>'''
```

Like I say, I've isolated so the "+" gets added but cannot figure the element around the + as a separate trigger.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks